# strcpy anamoly, underfined behaviour

Tags: macos, strcpy

```
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
     char *s;
     strcpy(s,"asdqw");
     strcpy(s,s+2);
     return 0;
}
```

This program is not showing up any error when run in linux system, it works fine.
But when on running in mac osx, it is showing **abort trap : 6**.
Why is this so happening so?

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate memory to `s`. Like this:

```
char *s = malloc(100);
```

Otherwise, undefined behaviour is caused. Since the behaviour is undefined, it working on Linux and not working on OS X are both reasonable.

Also, as @Florian Zwoch wisely points out, the second `strcpy()` operates on overlapping memory areas, which invokes undefined behaviour again. This is because `strcpy()` doesn't allow memory areas overlapping. You may want to use `memmove(s, s + 2, sizeof (s + 2));`, which allows the destination and source to overlap.

Comment: additionally the 2nd strcpy operates on overlapping memory areas. this behavior is undefined.

Comment: The answer you said @sun is not a problem here, it still pops same erroe.

Comment: [link](http://demin.ws/blog/english/2011/07/14/strcpy-on-overlapped-strings/) This clearly explains overlapping memory problem.

Comment: @aswinmythili `malloc()` is not the only problem here. Both the lack of `malloc()` and the use of `strcpy()` are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can run "Valgrind" on Linux and see if is there any error about memory.

[Valgrind easy Tutorial](http://arantxa.ii.uam.es/~talf1/valgrind.pdf) This is an easy tutorial how to use it.

It's because it could be a memory problem.